# Angular2 ngFor adding numbers from index ++

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

Am trying to increment the index value to create a list with numbers 1,2,3,4

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of queue.truckQueus; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
      <td>{{i ++ }}</td> //this throws an error
      <td>{{item.truck.reg_no}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How do i add the numbers from 1

I have also tried adding via

```
{{i += 1}}
```

But am always getting an error expression is expected. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: `{{ i + 1 }}` ?

Comment: Hmm I've never tried it before .. but maybe create a function in your .ts file that will do the calculation and returns it? So in the view you would have {{ calc(i) }}

Comment: Remove the space and try {{ i++ }}

Answer (score 1):

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of queue.truckQueus; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
      <td>{{i + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{item.truck.reg_no}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This must work.

As mentioned in the docs.

**JavaScript expressions that have or promote side effects are prohibited, including:**

- assignments (=, +=, -=, ...)
- new
- chaining expressions with ; or ,
- increment and decrement operators (++ and --)

[Read Here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)